# Reading data from BMP file in C

Tags: c, bitmap, base64

I have a problem with reading pixels from bmp file. It might be something with padding at the end of row or the base64 padding. I have no clue. I've been struggling with this for some days and can't move on because the next task requires this one to be solved.
I only share important parts of the code, since reading bmp header worked fine (tests had 0 failures).

**bmp.c**

```
struct pixel* read_data(FILE* stream, const struct bmp_header* header){
  if(stream == NULL || header == NULL){
    return 0;
  }
  // w == 1 && p == 1;   w == 2 && p == 2;   w == 3 && p == 3;   w == 4 && p == 0  
  int padding = header->width % 4; 
  int num_of_pixels = header->width * header->height;
  struct pixel* Pixel[num_of_pixels];

  fseek(stream, 54, SEEK_SET); //move 54B (header size)
  int index_p = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < header->height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < header->width; j++){
      Pixel[index_p] = malloc(sizeof(struct pixel));
      fread(&(Pixel[index_p]->blue), 1, 1, stream); 
      fread(&(Pixel[index_p]->green), 1, 1, stream); 
      fread(&(Pixel[index_p]->red), 1, 1, stream); 
      index_p++;
    }
    fseek(stream, padding, SEEK_CUR);  //padding at the end of row
  }
  return *Pixel;
}
```

**bmp.h**

```
struct pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
    //uint8_t alpha;
} __attribute__((__packed__));

/**
 * Read the pixels
 *
 * Reads the data (pixels) from stream representing the image. If the stream
 * is not open or header is not provided, returns `NULL`.
 *
 * @param stream opened stream, where the image data are located
 * @param header the BMP header structure
 * @return the pixels of the image or `NULL` if stream or header are broken
 */
struct pixel* read_data(FILE* stream, const struct bmp_header* header);
```

**header if needed** (basically we use only 24bit color)

```
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

**main.c** I do not need to assign any variables to called functions because we have a program for testing this, I just have to call them in main

```
int main(){

  struct bmp_header* header;
  FILE *stream = fopen("./assets/square.2x3.bmp", "rb");
  header = read_bmp_header(stream);
  read_data(stream, header);
  read_bmp(stream);
  struct bmp_image* image;
  image = malloc(sizeof(struct bmp_image));
  free_bmp_image(image);  
  fclose(stream);
  return 0;
}
```

**testing** (there are more tests, but this should be enough)

```
1: 
FILE* stream = "Qk0+AAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABABgAAAAAAAgAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA/wAAAP8AAAA="; // base64 encoded stream
struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);
fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET);
Assertion 'read_data(stream, header) == "/wAAAP8A"' failed. [got "/wAAFctV"]

2: 
FILE* stream = "Qk1GAAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAIAAAABABgAAAAAABAAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAP8A/wAAAA=="; // base64 encoded stream
struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);
fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET);
Assertion 'read_data(stream, header) == "/wAAAAAAAAD/AP8A"' failed. [got "/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"]
```

So after the "==" is expected result and in the brackets is my the result from my code. As I mentioned, it might be something with padding, since it starts well but doesn't end well.
Thanks for help.

Comment: regarding: `  if(stream == NULL || header == NULL){
    return 0;
  }`  This should already be tested, when the stream was opened and when this function was called.  So no need to re-check it here.

Comment: regarding; `FILE* stream = "Qk0+AAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABABgAAAAAAAgAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA/wAAAP8AAAA=";`  this does NOT look like a .bmp file on a disk.  What am I missing?

Comment: regarding; `int padding = header->width % 4;`  This fails to allow for byte width of each pixel and what is needed is not the number of bytes into the next multiple of 4, but rather the number of bytes needed to make the row a multiple of 4 bytes

Comment: regarding: `fseek(stream, 54, SEEK_SET);` this is not a valid calculation.  Suggest extract 'offset' to pixel data,  then move 'file pointer' to beginning of file, then move 'file pointer' forward the 'offset' bytes.

Comment: regarding: `struct pixel* Pixel[num_of_pixels];`  This declares an array of pointers to pixels, it does NOT declare any array that contains the pixels  and since this is on the stack, it 'goes out of scope' when the function exits.  Suggest calling `malloc()` or `calloc()` to acquire allocated memory to hold the pixels

Comment: regarding; `for(int i = 0; i < header->height; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < header->width; j++){`  this will only work if the number of padding bytes in each row of the image is 0. I.E. it will only work 1/4 (25percent) of the time

Comment: OT:  regarding the calls to `fread()` for safety and for robust code, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `Pixel[index_p] = malloc(sizeof(struct pixel));`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) this is very inefficient as the data is 3 bytes while the pointer is 4 or 8 bytes.

Comment: an item to consider:  the data on the disk is in little Endian byte order.  Many CPUs have the data in little Endian order, but not ALL CPUs are little Endian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Set padding to `(4-((3*width)%4))%4`

**Long answer**:

Your code included:

```
int padding = header->width % 4; 

//Some lines of code

fseek(stream, padding, SEEK_CUR);
```

In a bitmap, padding is added until each row is a multiple of 4 bytes. You took padding as `width % 4`.

First off, each pixel takes 3 bytes(for rgb). So it should be `(3*width)%4`. Next, we need to subtract it from 4 bytes (Since padding is 4-`pixels occupied`). So padding would be `4-((3*width)%4)`. Another small modification, if `(3*width)%4==0` then padding would come to be 4 (whereas, we expect it to be 0). So we take another mod4 just to be sure

So padding would come out to be  `(4-((3*width)%4))%4`

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by user Craig Estey in the comments, its better to use sizeof(struct pixel) instead of 3

Comment: Ok I added 
`int padding = 4 - (header->width * 3) % 4;
  if(padding == 4){
    padding = 0;
  }
` to my code but the tests give me this error "Message string too long". Just from looking at the code, I cannot find anything that would cause this error. Any idea?

Comment: @Tchiggy Not really sure. But based on code I'm assuming you have a 2px by 3px image. Can you try `printf`ing the values being read before the function returns?

Comment: printf-ing seems correct (prints a total of 6 pixels). Yep currently using 2x3 image, but the sizes in the tests may vary. I will see at the next test.

Comment: `FILE* stream = "Qk0+AAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAEAAAABABgAAAAAAAgAAAAjLgAAIy4AAAAAAAAAAAAA/wAAAP8AAAA="; // base64 encoded stream
struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);
fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET);
Assertion 'read_data(stream, header) == "/wAAAP8A"' failed. [got "/wAARaJV"]` so once again, my output is wrong

Comment: For the other tests, the start is once again good, but then it prints random chars, that are not even in input stream.

Comment: @Tchiggy on an unrelated note, are you sure about the return type of the  function in  bitmap.c? You declared an array of struct pointers and are returning the 0th element. That means only 1 pixel value is being returned. Apart from that sorry. Can't seem to figure out the issue

Comment: More correct would be to replace `3` with `sizeof(struct pixel)`