# Can not clone image using pixel struct in C

Tags: c, clone, bmp

Hello I am still new for C. I am using Clion c17 to read and copy the bmp pixel.
I have check that I can copy the header properly when I was actually reading the real file hex numbers and my values. I am not sure where I did wrong in my allocated pixel. it seems that I did not copy it properly or my code is not correct. Please if anyone can help me stop my problem. please let me know.
I was refering this code [Reading data from BMP file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61360044/reading-data-from-bmp-file-in-c) to write the following code... but it did not work...

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
} Pixel;

Pixel* read_bmp_pixels(FILE* stream, BMPHeader* header,  Pixel* pixels) {
    int padding = (4 - (header->width_px * sizeof(Pixel)) % 4) % 4;

    if (pixels == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate memory for pixel data.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fseek(stream, 54, SEEK_SET);
    int index_p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < header->width_px; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < header->height_px; j++) {
            fread(&(pixels[index_p].blue), 1, 1, stream);
            fread(&(pixels[index_p].green), 1, 1, stream);
            fread(&(pixels[index_p].red), 1, 1, stream);
            index_p++;
        }
        fseek(stream, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    //print_pixels(pixels, header->width_px * header->height_px);

    return pixels;
}
void copy(){
 Pixel *small_pixel = malloc(num_of_small_pixels * sizeof(Pixel));
    Pixel *big_pixel = malloc(num_of_big_pixels * sizeof(Pixel));
    if (small_pixel == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate memory for pixel data.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (big_pixel == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate memory for pixel data.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Pixel *read1= read_bmp_pixels(small_file, bmpHeader[0], small_pixel);
 FILE* test = fopen("test.bmp", "wb");
    if (!test) {
        printf("Error: could not open output BMP file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

// Write BMP header to the output file
    fseek(test, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(small_header, sizeof(char), 54, test);
    rewind(test);
    fseek(test, 54, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%s", big_buffer);
// Write the pixel data to the output file
    int num_pixels = bmpHeader[1]->width_px * bmpHeader[1]->height_px;
    int bytes_per_pixel = bmpHeader[0]->bits_per_pixel / 8;
    int row_padding = (4 - (bmpHeader[0]->width_px * bytes_per_pixel) % 4) % 4;
    print_pixels(small_pixel, bmpHeader[0]->width_px * bmpHeader[0]->height_px);
    for (int i = bmpHeader[0]->height_px - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmpHeader[0]->width_px; j++) {
            fwrite(&small_pixel[i * bmpHeader[0]->width_px + j].blue, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, test);
            fwrite(&small_pixel[i * bmpHeader[0]->width_px + j].green, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, test);
            fwrite(&small_pixel[i * bmpHeader[0]->width_px + j].red, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, test);
        }
        // Write row padding
        fwrite(&row_padding, 1, row_padding, test);
    }

    fclose(test);
    }
```

Comment: "it did not work" -- OK but what happened? Since you're dealing with images, it's probably useful to show them too. This code is incomplete, referencing various variables of which you don't show the definition nor the value they will have when the code runs, if the problem is related to them we would have no way to say what's wrong.

Comment: Show the `fopen` for `stream` (the output stream). Doing `rewind` before `fseek` is unnecessary and may be problematic. Are your BMP structures packed?